# Must Dislay the types not in for loop

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Hi friends am using a code in which I particularly mention a few items to be mandatory for selection now if any of the item is not selected then on click of the button it must toast a message with that missing item. Below is the code.

```
imageTypeMandatory = new String[] {"A","F","K","I","PROOF","LAND","BANK","INVOICE"};

for(int iCopy=0;iCopy<imageTypeMandatory.length;iCopy++){   if(imageTypeMandatory[iCopy].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dataOne.getString(0).trim())){
mandatoryCount++;
}
```

Here if i dint select any of the above items like A and F then i t must pop up with the missing item. Say "A and F"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all elements in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and in each iteration - *delete* the element from the set.

When the number of trials is done - the set contains all the element that were not chosen.

Something along the lines of:

```
    String[] imageTypeMandatory = new String[] {"A","F","K","I","PROOF","LAND","BANK","INVOICE"};
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s : imageTypeMandatory) set.add(s.toLowerCase());
    for(int iCopy=0;iCopy<imageTypeMandatory.length;iCopy++) {   
            set.remove(dataOne.getString(0).trim());
    }
    System.out.println(set); //or any other way to use the result
```

Comment: hi can you explain with example as am just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If ur if-statement. Put all missing Strings in a

```
String missing=missings+imageTypeMandatory[iCopy]
```

and then Toast the missing

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), missing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```